# What happens to the "last" of infinite beads (decreasing exponentially in mass) colliding on a straight line?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, collision

After reading a comment below I edited the question to simplify it.
Imagine infinite beads on an infinite straight line, all at rest. The distance between all beads is finite. The mass of the first bead is $m_0 \lt \infty$. The relation between the masses of the beads: $m_j=Cm_i$, where $0\lt C \lt 1$.
We give the first bead a velocity $v_0=U$ and subsequently, the bead collides head-on and perfectly elastic with the next bead, which on its turn collides with the third one, etc.
Will the process of collisions go on to infinity or does this depend on $C$?
If so will the beads "at infinity" reach relativistic speeds?
This is no homework question! I'm just interested and came up with this question myself.

Comment: I might misunderstand the text, but I don't think your geometry is correct. I'm not clear how the first mass strikes the second "head-on" the way that you described it unless $d=0$.  Also, it's not immediately obvious to me that you can ignore the mutual gravitational attraction between the masses if you're going to a limit of having infinitely many of them.

Comment: If the first mass is finite then the second mass is less which is less than the third, etc. ($0\lt c \lt 1$) but you're correct, I didn't mention that the first mass doesn't interact gravitationally with the second, etc.If the first mass makes a circle with radius $d$ and the distance between all masses is $d$ then each mass hits the next one head-on.

Comment: This is exactly what is the case. But thanks for the comment. I edited.

Comment: @Brick Assume there is an infinite massless ceiling above (parallel to) the infinite massive 2d plate. The spheres are all hanging on a rope (all with an equal length $l$) attached to the ceiling.  The points of attachment to the ceiling lie all on a straight line. The spheres are all rotating (*if*, after infinite time) in a plane parallel to the plate (or ceiling). The radius of the circles on which the masses rotate is equal to their mutual distances, $d$.

Comment: @Brick So if I let the first mass rotate on such a circle it hits the second circle head-on, which will therefore also start to rotate on a circle with radius $d$. Etc.

Comment: That helps. I imagined the plane of the circles being the one that contained the line of balls and their mounting points, which would be perpendicular to the ceiling, rather than parallel to it as you've clarified now. Might try to "circle" back later to the kinematics of the question with that clarification.

Comment: This honestly sounds like a mathematics question than physics, why don’t you try to ask there?

Comment: @user208685 The right answer has already been given below! It's a simple application of the formulae of an elastic collision (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_collision).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple kinematics of a head-on perfectly elastic Newtonian collision between two spherical bodies $m_i$ and $m_j$, such that $m_j/m_i = c$, $0<= c <= 1$, and immediately before the collision $u_i=U$, and $u_j=0$, shows that $m_j$ leaves the collision with velocity $v_j=2U/(1+c)$. So for $c=1$ there will be an infinite set of collisions, in which each ball will be moving at velocity $U$ after it has been hit (as you surmised). But for ***any*** $c<1$, the velocity will increase with every collision without limit. Note that you will get essentially the same kinematics if you ditch the massive plate, ropes, and circular motion, and just use a row of billiard balls sitting on a frictionless table (or beads on a wire).

You mentioned relativistic velocity in your question. If you introduce special relativity into the model then there is the fairly insurmountable problem that you can't have rigid bodies (and hence no perfectly elastic collisions).

Comment: I made the situation indeed more complicated than necessary! I'll edit the question into the beads on a wire-case to make it more simple! One thing though. Why you set  $u_j  =0$?

Comment: @descheleschilder I set uj=0 on the assumption that initially only the first ball was moving - if that is not the then you would need to specify the initial velocity for each ball j. See the edit "...and immediately before the collision.." to my answer.

Comment: Shouldn't $U_0=U$ suffice?

Comment: @descheleschilder Yes, with the way you have now written your question, that is sufficient (so long as you assume all the other beads are initially stationary).

Comment: I'll edit again!